# crypto HFT architecture

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading, high-frequency, tick-data, low-latency

[image]

This architecture is designed to minimize latency with the help of busy-spinning and CPU affinity locks(meaning each producer/consumer thread running in only one core), preventing a thread from wandering between CPUs and losing time on context switching.

On a side note : I am using lock-free ringbuffers.

I am going to use ZMQ for PUB/SUB architecture. I really don't know if this is a very bad choice for a low latency application which is what i am going to design. Could anyone please point me why its bad ? and what are the alternatives here ?

Answer (score -3):

I can show you [here](https://www.sissoftwarefactory.com/blog/how-do-i-design-high-frequency-trading-systems-and-its-architecture-part-i/) what we did, and how we architected several production-ready low latency trading (achieving under 2 microsec tick-to-trade)

Note: we did all this using software-based only systems (no FPGAs)

Comment: good series of articles! thanks! I see you mentioned about disruptor pattern which uses lock free ring buffers between producer and consumer threads. so that is way better than your solution on part 3 which is busy spinning with lock synchronization

Comment: also you have mentioned avoid OOP much as you can, why ? you dont have even one class in your code ?

Comment: please reply @Ariel Silahian

Comment: Well lock-free rings are not better in terms of latency and throughput. At least in our case. BTW, we measure every single thing we do to get the best solution. And the results were that busy-wait was way better

Comment: For the OOP, you may still use it, but you want to avoid virtual functions, polymorphism, etc. All that could take some time out if your latencies

Comment: you could also use busy wait on consumer threads in disruptor pattern. which means you get to do busy wait + lockfree ring buffers. But you are suggesting busy wait + locks.
doesnt make any sense @ Ariel Silahian

Comment: are you selling fraud services ? plus your articles are all vague.

Comment: sorry for the late response. You must understand the diff between high throughput and low latency

Comment: I agree with @dopller. This poster seems to be selling fraud services. There's a lot of vague cargo cult engineering here, and the claims seem to be an assembled bunch of hearsay. The example just shows a few trivial code samples, far from an actual trading system. The claims (e.g. "pre-allocating 10-element bid-ask array") don't make any sense at all - the price moves and you're out of scope and you'd have lost track of other levels.

Comment: @ArielSilahian has big mouth, nothing else

Comment: All good guys. My posts are not intended to give away an entire HFT system from scratch, but allow to my audience get what needs to be done. Nothing else.

Comment: In another note.... wondering if any of you have ever deployed an ultra-low latency HFT trading operation? Most likely not. I just wanted to give some sense. Good luck

Comment: @ArielSilahian I have. And I have brokerage statements showing anywhere up to 10% ADV, and Corvil screenshots to back this. There are so many more profitable ways to sell snake oil than to pretend to be a low latency platform developer, so I really don't get why you have to die on this hill.